# Is it possible to do pull request reviews in GitLab?

Tags: github, gitlab, pull-request

I found instructions on how to do pull requests in Github but I am not finding information on if it's possible to do it with GitLab. If it is the setup is different and doesn't follow Githubs instructions.

https://help.github.com/articles/reviewing-proposed-changes-in-a-pull-request/

Comment: If I am not mistaken Pull requests are called Merge requests on Gitlab: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/

Comment: Have you tried searching the internet for, say, "gitlab pull request"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitLab uses slightly different terminology. GitLab merge requests are the equivalent of GitHub pull requests.

See [Merge requests](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/) in GitLab's documentation.